How does the spectrum of the Laplace operator change under small deformations?
Say we have a closed domain $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$ and consider the spectrum of the Laplace operator in this domain --- values of $\lambda$ such that the Helmholtz equation $\Delta f=-\lambda f$ has a solution in $\Omega$, subject to the boundary condition that $\nabla f\cdot\mathbf{n}=0$ at every point on the boundary of $\Omega$ where $\mathbf{n}$ is normal to the surface at the point.
Suppose now that we deform $\Omega$ slightly.
Questions:

Is there some way to quantify how much the spectrum of the Laplace operator changes under a deformation?

(I am particularly interested in this.) Is it true that higher eigenvalues are more sensitive to deformations? By "sensitive", I mean that higher frequencies change more than lower frequencies under small deformations.

How can these questions be made more precise?



@YvesDaoust Thanks! But how might we ensure that the deformed surface is still smooth, so that we can still talk about solving the Helmholtz equation on it? If we express the deformation as a movement of boundary points along normals as you suggest, presumably it suffices to assume that the scaling factor $\lambda$ varies smoothly over the surface?

There are quantitative stability estimates for this, but maybe not what you want. I think you can show that if the domain has volume of unit ball and is “close” (symmetric difference of), then the two eigenvalues will be close.

The Weyl law and associated Weyl conjecture give some estimates on the asymptotics of $\lambda_n$ in terms of $\Omega$

In the simple case of uniform scaling, $x\to y =\alpha\ x\ \partial_{x,x} \to \alpha^2 \ \partial_{y,y}$  with eigenvalue scaling $\lambda_{i,j\dots}^2$ of $$-\Delta_{ij\dots} \ f_{ij\dots} = \lambda_{i,j\dots} \ \ f_{ij\dots}$$ one has a simple scaling by $\lambda_{i,j\dots}\ \to \ \frac{\lambda_{i,j\dots}}{\alpha ^2}$.  So, eg in n-spherical coordinates the radial spectrum changes while the modes and spectrum of the spherical Laplacian is scale independent.
For the rest of the question see the classical article of Marc Kac  'Can you hear the Shape of a Drum' and index theory in general.
